# Is it possible to allow users to search for an address, and attach a pin to a location like in Google Maps using Leaflet? How do I do this?

Tags: maps, location, leaflet

I've read about how some sites use streets data and overlay it over their map tiles. Is this necessary in leaflet? I think the attaching of a marker is fairly well-covered in the Leaflet documentation, but I'm not sure whether there's a (ideally reasonably easy) way to give it the full search for address functionality in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible - you'll need a geocoding web service, like Google's, that you can hand an address and will give you back a lat/lon coordinate, which you can then plot onto Leaflet. I believe MapQuest has a free one; not sure if there's an API limit or anything along those lines: http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/

In fact, I think this [template site](http://mapbox.com/map-sites/dc-properties/) from MapBox, though it doesn't use Leaflet, hooks into MapQuest for it's geocoding. You might be able to use that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest offers two Geocoding Web Services, which will take an address and convert it to latitude and longitude coordinates.

- [MapQuest Geocoding Web Service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/) (licensed data, meaning, the 'behind the scenes' geocoding data is commercially-available data)
- [MapQuest Open Geocoding Web Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/) (open data, meaning, the 'behind the scenes' data is open, generated by users of the OpenStreetMap community).

The Open Geocoding Web Service is brand new!  For more information, check out the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com) and [Developer Network Forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums).

Comment: Jharahush and @iani Is there a javascript API for the same (reverse geocoding in leaflet) ?